# Loop to iterate up parent nodes until it finds specific tag

Tags: c#, loops, xelement

What I'm doing is finding a specific value within an XML document and then I want to iterate upwards through each parent until it finds the parent with a specific tag name.

```
List<XElement> fieldReferences = new List<XElement>();
fieldReferences.AddRange(element.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("descendant::nameValue[@idref='{0}']", fieldName)));
fieldReferences.AddRange(element.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("descendant::nameValue[@value='{0}']", fieldName)));

string parentIterator = ".Parent";
string attributeValue = ".Attribute('id').Value";
string parentElementName = ".Name";
foreach (var value in fieldReferences)
{
    var parentField = string.Format("{0}{1}", parentIterator, parentElementName);
    while (value + parentField != "private" || value + parentField != "public")
        {
            // keep appending .Parent until it finds what it needs
        }
    //var parentField = value.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Attribute("id").Value;
    outputFields.Add(parentField, name.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

The issue that I'm having is that parentField will always be evaluated as a string so it'll never actually check the .Parent.Name property of value.

I don't work often with C# so I'm sure there's a much easier way to do this so my question is: How can I get my parentField string to evaluate the way I want OR how can I do this in a different way to achieve the same end result?

EDIT: Here's what my xml looks like. The XPAthSelectElement gets the nameValue element and I want to iterate through each parent element until I find the private tag

```
<private id="I need to iterate upwards through each parent element until I find this one">
    <value>
      <request>
        <nameValues>
          <nameValue idref="I found this" />
          <nameValue value=""/>
        </nameValues>
      </request>
    </value>
  </private>
```

Comment: I've read your question a few times, and I'm still having some issues figuring out what you are trying to do.  Can you give some real examples of some of the XML, and the types of things you want to match?

Comment: XElement has a parent property which will give you another XElement, so why do you need to convert to a string?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement_properties(v=vs.110).aspx.  value.Parent gives you the parent, then from there, get the info on the parent.

Comment: Yea, sorry it's a little difficult to explain.

Comment: Here's my XML

<private id="I need to iterate upwards through each parent element until I find this one">
                  <value>
                    <request>
                      <nameValues>
                        <nameValue idref="something to find" />
                        <nameValue value=""/>
                      </nameValues>
                    </request>
                  </value>
                </private>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you don't actually need to do this many string operations to then go crazy with XPath. Once you found your child target element, you can just use the `Parent` property on the `XElement` iteratively until you find the `XElement` with a private/public tag. So that gives us this code:

```
foreach (XElement element in fieldReferences)
{
    XElement currentElement = element;
    while (currentElement.Parent != null)
    {
        currentElement = currentElement.Parent;
        if (currentElement.Name == "private" || currentElement.Name == "public") {
            outputFields.Add(currentElement, /* not sure what you want here */);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So `currentElement` would start out as the element with the `nameValue` tag from your example. In the while loop, each iteration `currentElement` changes to its parent node until there is no more parent or `currentElement` has become a `private` or a `public` tag. If the latter is the case, it gets appended to your result.

Comment: Can't assign it to element because it is a foreach iteration variable is what it says.

Comment: My bad, it can be simply assigned to a new variable. Edited my answer.

Comment: Yea, that's what I ended up doing, I'm going to try it out now and let you know.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Im using XmlDocument but can still be solved the same way. I was hoping for a better way without having to write my own method. I should have just used intellisense to realize I would have to write a method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`XElement.Ancestors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339717(v=vs.110).aspx) function to get a list of all the elements that contain the nodes you found, then just select the ones you want using LINQ. No need for any loops.

```
var results = fieldReferences.Select(element => element.Ancestors()
                                                       .Where(ancestor => ancestor.Name == "public" ||
                                                                          ancestor.Name == "private")
                                                       .FirstOrDefault());
```

Note that this will go all the way up the tree, and may have issues if there are multiple matching ancestors (or no matching ancestor).  Let me know if that is a problem for you, and what result you want in that case, and I can make adjustments.

Comment: The only issue with this approach is that there could potentially be many items in my fieldReferences list

Comment: It should find the right element for all of them. is that not what you want?  If `fieldReferences`contains 3 `XElement` instances, `results` will contain 3 `XElement` instances that are ancestors of those named "public" or "private" elements.

Comment: Now that I have something working I will add this approach to my list of refactoring opportunities, thank you!